# System boots straight into Windows without showing GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows but I did not disable *secure boot* as someone told me it could cause problems with boot loader. So when installation finished and I rebooted, the system went straight into Windows. I went to *Ubuntu IRC Support* and they told me to turn off the secure boot and reinstall Ubuntu. I did that but my system still
boot into windows.

This is a picture of partitions on my system:

[image]

This is my first Ubuntu install on my new laptop.
I followed *everdaylinux guide* to install it and I used *something else* option.

Answer (score 9):

Re-installing GRUB is almost certainly overkill, and carries a small risk of messing things up. Instead, try this:

1. Boot to Windows.
2. Open an *Administrator* Command Prompt window by right-clicking the Command Prompt icon and selecting the option to run it as Administrator.
3. Type `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`
4. Reboot.
5. If you boot into Ubuntu but GRUB did not give you a menu or if that menu did not include Windows, type `sudo update-grub` in a Terminal.

That should fix it. Alternatively, instead of steps #2-3, you could try the third-party [EasyUEFI,](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) which gives you a GUI menu for rearranging EFI boot priorities. Some EFIs provide similar functionality in their setup utilities. You can also do the same thing with `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu, but that sometimes fails due to bugs in either `efibootmgr` or EFIs, and it's harder to explain than is the same procedure with `bcdedit` in Windows.

Comment: i did that cmd thing and was successful rebooted and it went straight into windows and then i used super grub 2 to boot into ubuntu and typed  sudo update-grub in a Terminal. though still it does not show grub let me try easy bcd

Comment: aslo easy bcd added ubuntu entry in boot but when i select it ... it does not boot

Comment: Please boot into Ubuntu and run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL back here. Also, what make and model computer do you have?

Comment: Worked! So much simpler than live boot.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a bit of a process, so fair warning beforehand: it gets a little complex.

You'll have to boot into the Ubuntu LiveCD, and select *try Ubuntu*.
 From there, mount your root partition. You can do this by going into the file manager and then clicking on "20GB Filesystem" (or something very similar to that - you'll know it when you see it on the side).
 Now open a terminal and type  `sudo -i`

That will transfer you to a root shell , so be careful!

Run `cd /media/ubuntu`

then type `ls` and hit enter.

You should see 1 (maybe 2) options . One will have a very strange name, the other one will have a label denoting as a CDrom.

If there is a second entry , go to the  very strange name by typing `cd foldername` and hitting enter. Then execute

`grub-install /dev/sda; chroot . grub-update`

The output will be "done." Reboot, and your bootloaded should be back in place with your choice.

Comment: i do not have a cd but i do have a usb from which i installed ubuntu  u can see http://paste.ubuntu.com/12139261/                          i tried its showing something different

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12139267/

Comment: have you tried [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: nope brb let me give this a try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: so i ran boot repair in ubuntu live usb this is what i got http://paste.ubuntu.com/12139346/

Comment: http://imgur.com/HNIUBWR    and http://imgur.com/PeUr66J

Comment: im guessing u guys didn't check comments ?

Answer (score 0):

Write the [Super Grub disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/) to a USB drive and boot from it.

Start Ubuntu.

If you are in Ubuntu, open a terminal and type

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12150106/

Comment: Try `sudo update-grub` and then the above again.

Answer (score -2):

**ISSUE --**

> " I CAN'T ACCESS THE GRUB (UBUNTU) MENU BECAUSE MY LAPTOP/PC BOOTS
>   DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS. "

**SOLUTION --**

> " PRESS THE KEY THAT OPENS YOUR BIOS SETTINGS DURING START. UNDER BOOT
>   CONFIGURATIONS,YOU SEE **UEFI BOOT ORDER** , CLICK ON **/OS BOOT
>   MANAGER/** (ON TOP) , PRESS F5/F6 TO CHANGE THE PRIORITY OF WINDOWS /
>   UBUNTU . KEEP UBUNTU ON TOP.

VOILA! IT'S DONE. :)